# using a custom deleter for std::shared_ptr on a direct3d11 object

Tags: c++, c++11, directx-11

When i use an std::shared_ptr and need a custom deleter, i usually make a member function of the object to facilitate it's destruction like this:

```
class Example
{
public:
    Destroy();
};
```

and then when i use the shared ptr, i just make it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Example> ptr(new Example, std::mem_fun(&Example::Destroy));
```

Problem is, right now i'm working with d3d11, and i would like to use the com release functions as an std::shared_ptr custom deleter, like this

```
std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Device> ptr(nullptr, std::mem_fun(&ID3D11Device::Release));
```

but i get this error:

```
error C2784: 'std::const_mem_fun1_t<_Result,_Ty,_Arg> std::mem_fun(_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(_Arg) const)' : could not deduce template argument for '_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(_Arg) const' from 'ULONG (__stdcall IUnknown::* )(void)'
```

and then when i explicitly specify the template paramters like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Device> ptr(nullptr, std::mem_fun<ULONG, ID3D11Device>(&ID3D11Device::Release));
```

I get this error,

```
error C2665: 'std::mem_fun' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

can someone explain why i can't use this function as a deleter?

note: don't suggest I use CComPtr, i'm using msvc++ express edition :\

Comment: Can you use `std::mem_fn` instead of `std::mem_fun`?

Comment: `std::mem_fun` is deprecated, use `std::mem_fn`

Comment: use lambdas or `std::bind`, that's easier to understand.

Comment: Try `static_cast<ULONG (ID3D11Device::*)(void)> (&ID3D11Device::Release)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about this?

```
std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Device> ptr(nullptr, [](ID3D11Device* ptr){ptr->Release();} );
```

Comment: works fine, 2 questions though. 1) why does it still call the deleter when it's constructed with nullptr. 2) what would the return type of that lambda be? i'm a little new to them :\

Comment: @FatalCatharsis : This lambda's return type is `void`.

Comment: @ildjarn : wait, not the lambda's return type. sry, i meant what type is the lambda itself?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis : Lambdas have anonymous (unnameable) types, each unique and generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
struct Releaser{
    void operator()(ID3D11Device* p){
        p->Release();

    };

};


std::shared_ptr<ID3D11Device> ptr(nullptr, Releaser());
```